# How to get the number of characters in a javascript string

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, string-length

string.length returns the number of 16-bit characters in a string, thus the length of a string '1.2 in exponent is 1.2e0' is 25, because the e (\udc52) is 17-bit and is treated as 2 different unicode characters. This behavior may be useful for most of the cases in programming, what if I want to know the exact number of characters in a string (like, in the example above, 24 instead of 25). Is there a predefined method, tricks, hacks, or anything  to count number of characters instead of number of 16-bit characters?

**Note: The e in the example string is not alphabetic character E, it is the character that represents 'exponent' in IEEE 754 format**

Comment: http://developer.teradata.com/blog/jasonstrimpel/2011/11/javascript-string-length-and-internationalizing-web-applications

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, you can use `Array.from()`:

```
var string = "1.2 in exponent is 1.20";
var charCount = Array.from(string).length;
console.log(charCount); // returns 24
```